# Especificar Minetype en Intent para tipo geojson en Android

Tags: android, android-intent, geojson

Tengo una app que genera un track en formato `geojson` y me gustaría dar la posibilidad de compartir el archivo usando intent en Android, pero en `minetype` especifico `application/json` pero claro eso hace que cualquier app que pueda leer `json` se puede abrir.

¿Lo que quiero es si existe un minetype especifico para los `geojson`?

Comment: Puedes responderla tu mismo y aceptala. Eso seria lo correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un poco de información acerca del formato `GeoJSON`:

> **GeoJSON**: Este tipo de medio está destinado a las aplicaciones GeoJSON
> que actualmente utilizan los tipos de medios
> "application/vnd.geo+json" o "application/json", de los cuales hay
> varias categorías: mapeo web, bases de datos geoespaciales, API de
> procesamiento de datos geográficos, análisis de datos y servicios de
> almacenamiento y difusión de datos.

Pero actualmente el usar para archivos `GeoJSON` un `MIME TYPE`  :

```
application/vnd.geo+json
```

es [**obsoleto**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).

Este es el estatuto:

> El tipo de medio para texto **GeoJSON** es "application/geo+json" y
> está registrado en el registro "Tipos de medios" descrito en
>  [[RFC6838]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838). La entrada para "application/vnd.geo+json" en el mismo
> registro debe cambiar su estado para que sea "OBSOLETO" con un
> puntero al tipo de medio "application/geo+json" y una referencia
> agregada a este RFC.

por lo tanto **se debe usar** :

```
application/geo+json
```

o

```
application/json
```

Esta es la lista actual definida por la IANA:

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

En la [referencia](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/geo+json) `RFC7946` se define que el `mine-type` para archivos de formato `geojson`,

se puede definir con valor `application/json`

o bien específicamente `application/vnd.geo+json`